# Разделить строку на списки с одинаковыми символами

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть строка, которая состоит из несколько разных и в разный момент повторяющихся символов

**Пример:** `'<<<VVV>>>VVV'`

**Надо получить:** `['<<<', 'VVV', '>>>', 'VVV']` или `[['<', '<', '<'], ['V', 'V', 'V'], ['>', '>', '>'], ['V', 'V', 'V']]`

То есть надо разделять строку как только следующий символ становиться другим.

Подряд может идти также только один символ, в этом случае его надо отделять так же, как все остальные.

**Можно использовать любые библиотеки**

Как это сделать в **одну строку кода**? Если никак, то прошу показать самый короткий по коду вариант.

**Вот как сделал я**:

```
result = []
last_elem = string[0]
temp = []
for elem in string:
    if elem == last_elem:
        temp.append(elem)
    else:
        result.append(temp)
        temp = [elem]
        last_elem = elem
result.append(temp)
```

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/t6vjBe/1

Comment: @splash58,  а почему не оформить как ответ?

Comment: @MaxU возможно, я не прав, но мне тупо лень :)

Comment: @splash58, это аргумент! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы желаете в одну строку бессмысленно и беспощадно, то можно еще так извратиться:

```
s = '<<<VVV>>>VVV'

f = lambda s, ans = []: ans if len(s) == 0 else f(s[1:], [s[0]]) if len(ans) == 0 else f(s[1:], ans[:-1] + [ans[-1] + s[0]]) if s[0] == ans[-1][0] else f(s[1:], ans + [s[0]])

print(f(s))
```

Разбираю лямбду по кусочкам:

```
f = ans, если s - пустая;
  = f(s[1:], [s[0]]), если ans - пустой;
  = f(s[1:], ans[:-1] + [ans[-1] + s[0]]), если последний блок символов в ans совпадает с первым символом s
  = f(s[1:], ans + [s[0]]), если последний блок символов в ans не совпадает с первым символом s
```

В нормальном рекурсивном виде она же:

```
def f(s, ans = []):
    if len(s) == 0:
        return ans
    if len(ans) == 0 or s[0] != ans[-1][0]:
        return f(s[1:], ans + [s[0]])
    return f(s[1:], ans[:-1] + [ans[-1] + s[0]])
```

Answer (score 3):

попробуйте так:

```
import re

a = "<<<VVV>>>VVV"

res = [x[0] for x in re.findall(r"((.)\2*)", a)]
```

res:

```
['<<<', 'VVV', '>>>', 'VVV']
```

Comment: Не работает при условии, если подряд идёт только один одинаковый символ (Например, "<V>")

Comment: Изменил ответ. проверяйте

Answer (score 1):

это конечно не в одну строку, но пусть будет

```
def f(s):
    l=[0] + [i+1 for i, el in enumerate(zip(s[:-1], s[1:])) if el[0]!=el[1]] + [None]
    return [s[i:j] for i, j in zip(l[:-1], l[1:])]
```

`zip(s[:-1], s[1:])` создаём список, где каждый элемент это s[0] и s[1], s[1] и s[2], s[2] и s[3], и т.д.

`if el[0]!=el[1]` оставляем элементы где первый значение не равно второму т.е. моменты перехода с одного символа на другой

Comment: Очень круто. Однако, если объясните как это работает, буду очень признателен.